# Version Control for code yet to be unit tested

Tags: unit-testing, version-control, build, continuous-integration, cvs

My team has a dozen engineers, some of whom work on modules that will take 2-3 weeks to complete.

Now we integrate each module to the main branch of CVS only after unit testing is completed.

The problem with this is for a good 2-3 weeks the code sits only on an engineer's computer and is not under version control.

The programming language used is C.

Is there any elegant way to manage non unit tested code under version control.

Thanks

James

Comment: Why CVS?  With Git or Hg changes could be tracked, but witbout pushing.

Comment: With Git or Mercurial, those branches could actually be pushed to the server, and just not merged until they pass through whatever integration gate. For that matter, CVS and Subversion can do this too, they just make the merge step much less pleasant. The bottom line is, quit using poor tools in a broken workflow.

Comment: +1 for @robert: It's time to say bye-bye to CVS. The time invested learning Mercurial (I can't speak for git) will be repaid many, many times over in a smoother, saner workflow.

Answer (score 3):

Your process of 2-3 weeks before check-in to the "main" branch is not out-of-the-norm, as would be a similar re-design "root canal" effort (serious restructuring work that is sometimes necessary).

However, I would tend to get pretty nervous about that much time outside of version control.

1. Don't code angry.
2. Don't code drunk.
3. Don't code for a long time without version control
   "check-point".

A strong recommendation is that the local developer use Mercurial or Git for local version control for that 2-3 weeks, and then you can check the "finalized" project back into the (main) CVS branch.  They are *really* built for *exactly* that scenario.

That's what we do -- it works, and it makes diffs-and-patches and collaboration between individual developers quite trivial.

(For us, Mercurial is local, Subversion is the "main" version control system.)

Comment: +11 for "Don't code drunk"! In 1975, after a great Happy Hour on Hump Day, I dropped off a friend who was going to "just shut down the machines." The next morning we found him in the office in tears. He had destroyed the master copy of the assembly language operating system for an entire Computer Assisted Instruction system. Five of us spent the next 3 weeks disassembling variable-instruction-length, variable-data-length machine code (this was a Cincinnati Milacron 2200B). We lost all of the comments and all of the variable/label names. It almost killed the company.

Comment: OUCH!  That sounds *so* painful!  It puts to shame my stories on, "Don't code drunk."  (More than one story, never a good outcome.)  ;-))

Answer (score 2):

> ...for a good 2-3 weeks the code sits only on an engineer's computer and is not under version control...

Hm well to me programming outside of version control is like driving with reverse gear: technically doable but generally quite er counterproductive.

In that sense, I would say any other approach that somehow allows your developers to **continuously** keep their work under VC would be more *elegant* than nothing at all. For that, there are many known ways - googling for *version control branching strategy* shows plenty resources explaining your options and criteria how to choose.

Without experimenting it's rather hard to tell which of these options is a better fit for your project. When studying resources I refer to above I'd recommend to check details of what is usually called *Feature Branch*. This strategy rather closely matches the case you describe *"modules that will take 2-3 weeks to complete"* - although I wouldn't bet on that it's the best fit for your team.

Note also that at least for "internal" developers needs you have an option to use version control system other than old-fashioned and inconvenient CVS.

Comment: thanks for the feedback. I plan to set up a Continuous Integrations server for the merging process. Does Git or Mercurial offer only particular advantage for this activity. Thanks

Comment: advantages hm. None I can think of right now. On the contrary, I'd rather expect good [Continuous Integration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration) server to be _VC-agnostic_ so to speak. I mean I'd expect it to be able to support any widely used VCS, be it CVS or Git or Mercurial, whatever

Answer (score 1):

If your company policy requires all your code to be unit tested before checking in, I think it is pretty good policy, and you should do just that: write your unit tests, perhaps even before writing code.

But if I misunderstood you and it is just that there should be large *testing session* when everything is done, well, then it is too bad. You will definitely encounter pesky integration problems. If you cannot change that policy, at least have your local VCS. Also, you could have config with "featureX_Enabled" switches, and try not to forget to set it to '0' when checking in.

Anyway, switch to Git or Mercurial, they would be so much less painful to use.